# Javascript not entering the if condition

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working with html and javascript for a couple of days and I'm stuck at this point.  I need to take an answer for an mcq and display whether it is right or wrong
Why is the if condition not entered ?

I have just put a simple javascript using GetElemntById and .checked with .value 
this is not a school assignment this is some thing that i have been planning for a long time

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        document.write("In javascript");
            function myFunction()
            {
                document.write("In the function");
                if(document.getElementById('a1').checked)
                {
                    document.write("in if");
                    var x = document.getElementById('a1').value
                    document.write(x);
                }else
                {
                    document.write("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
                }

            }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <p> How much is 2+2 ?? </p>
    4 : <input type="radio" name="ans" id="a1" value="4"><br/ >
    5 : <input type="radio" name="ans" id="a2" value="5"><br/ >
    6 : <input type="radio" name="ans" id="a3" value="6"><br/ >
    7 : <input type="radio" name="ans" id="a4" value="7"><br/ >

    <button onClick="myFunction()">clickz</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: everything working as expected. what u found wrong?

Comment: don't use document.write() use alert or console.log if its for debugging.

Comment: It works .. check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xbSj5/

Comment: if u use document.write(). it erase the all DOM element and write only "In the function".

Comment: works fine  http://jsfiddle.net/smr88/

Answer (score 1):

`document.write()` call will clear all the contents on the web page if you call it after page loading is completed, which causes all of your radio buttons disappear.  So you won't get anything by `document.getElementById`.

Remove those `document.write` and use `console.log` or `alert` if you want to output any debug logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `document.write` once the document is loaded. If you do, your browser will open a new document that replaces the current, so, you cannot access any of your html content.
This is why your `document.getElementById()` returned `null`, and it was not possible to check the property `checked`.

Replace your `document.write()` by `alert()/console.log()`

```
<script>
    document.write("In javascript");
        function myFunction()
        {
            if(document.getElementById("a1").checked)
            {
                alert("in if");
                var x = document.getElementById('a1').value
                console.log(x);
            }else
            {
                alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            }

        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        document.write("In javascript");
            function myFunction()
            {

                if(document.getElementByName('ans').checked)
                {
                    document.write("in if");
                    var x = document.getElementById('a1').value
                    document.write(x);
                }else
                {
                    document.write("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
                }

            }
    </script>
```

your code will work only if you check 1st answer ,because you use `id` for that only ,change `document.getElementById`  to  `document.getElementByName`

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with document.write

If document.write is called a after a page has loaded, it will erase all the previous contents, which is the problem in your case.

If document.write is in the body, there is no such problem.

See this thread for more insight [why is document.write a bad practise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

As other saying. Main problem is with your **"document.write("In javascript");"*

It is clearing your input element before going through your condition.

Check it out fiddle example

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JeaSZ/)!

```
< script > function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById('a1').checked) {
        alert("in if")
        var x = document.getElementById('a1').value
        alert(x);
    } else {
        alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    }

} < /script>



<p>How much is 2+2 ??</p>
<div>
        <input type="radio" name="ans" id="a1" value="4"/>
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="ans" id="a2" value="5" />
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="ans" id="a3" value="6" />
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="ans" id="a4" value="7" />
        </br>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</div>
```